# Can we meditate on Lord Shiva during Sutak period?

Tags: shiva, belief, rituals, death, meditation

[Sutak](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/why-hindus-observe-sutak-after-a-deathbirth-in-near-family) is the period of abstention observed by the Hindus after birth or a death of a family member.

Can we mediate on Lord Shiva with Panchakshari Mantra during Sutak period?

Comment: You cannot do physical worship during sutak or ashuch but you can do any type of mental worship including meditation, and namasmarana (without mala or shakti japa technique).

Comment: No never. In sutak nobody drinks water of your home and you are not allowed to go in any temple too. You can do bhajan or japa for your loved one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. We can meditate on Lord during Asoucha or Sutak period which generally lasts for 13-15 days depending on region and caste.

[Sri Annadanam Chidambara Sastry](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?page_id=2)  says the following in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqGqEJFzPes) which is part of Dharma Sandhehalu telecasted on Telugu Channel Bhakthi TV.

> *Soucham* (cleanliness) is needed for works related to God. Like how we need a vehicle (milk or food or water) to carry medicine, rules are
>   needed (followed) for Daiva Pooja (worship). We should worship with *Suchi*
>   (purity) both internally and externally. Asouchi acquired during death
>   of relatives is called *Mrutaasoucha*. Asouchi acquired during birth
>   is called *Jatahasoucha*. Upasana is not allowed during Jatahasoucha
>   and Mrutaasoucha but those who are initiated with a mantra shouldn't
>   stop chanting the mantra. *Mantratyaage Daridrataha*.
>
> In Asoucha times, we can meditate in mind (mental meditation) without
>   moving lips. There is no dosha for mental meditation during Asoucha
>   days.

Comment: Are doing vrata also forbidden in sutak period? Even if we agreed on doing vrata without worrying about whether we will get merit of vrat or not, then its fine or not? Means, for some people getting merits/fruits of vrata is not much important, they just want to complete their vrata without gap (in love of God, in fruitless manner). Does it will be okay or they will be generating any kind of sin by doing this? Any idea?

Comment: @Rishabh Not sure of Vrata. I will check Garuda Purana and tell you